# How to update the rownumbers in View(), after deleting rows in a dataframe in R?

Tags: r

I have the following dataframe

```
R<-iris
View(R)
```

[image: gives me this]

After deleting a few rows

```
R<-R[-2:-5,]
View(R)
```

[image: I get this]

As you can see the row numbers initially were 1,2,3,4....
But after the deletion it is 1,6,7,8.......
I want the row numbers to be 1,2,3,.......... after the deletion, so that it is easier for me to reference.

Comment: rownames(R) =NULL;View(R)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can re-set the `rownames` as:

```
R<-iris
View(R)

R<-R[-2:-5,]

# Re-set the rownames. Starting with 1 till last row number
rownames(R) <- 1:nrow(R)

View(R)
```

Comment: Or using `slice` `slice(iris, -2:-5)`